Is it possible, with base branch protection, to close multiple PRs on Github by pushing a _single_ commit that merges these?
I am participating in development of a code base that is on a Github Enterprise server, and there is branch protection (settings documented below) in place for master. I have 3 PRs opened, each with its own fix/feature branch tip that diverged from the same commit on master at one point, and all of the PRs have been approved and all of the commits on each of the branches, are signed.
Because I do and want to continue to work with Git directly, and have as little as possible to do with Github's Web pages, I thought I would just close the PRs by locally merging all of the branches (one for each PR) with a single new commit, which was effortless, obviously -- I have now new tip of master (locally) that has three parent commits -- one for each branch tip of its PR.
When I try to push master to the remote end with git push origin master, the latter refuses to play along and I get back the following fatal error:
Enumerating objects: 26, done.
Counting objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 1.43 KiB | 1.43 MiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), completed with 4 local objects.
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.
remote: error: Changes must be made through a pull request.
To github.com:foo/bar.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:foo/bar.git'

My colleague tells me I would have to merge each PR (locally) with its own commit, "sequentially" so that instead of the current (with a master I can't seem to push):
*---.   b409f01 (master)
|\ \ \
| | | * 92f9834 (PR #3)
| |_|/
|/| |
| | * 0547677 (PR #2)
| |/
|/|
| * e6aa276 (PR #1)
|/
* fb00b60 (origin/master)

...I have the more "amenable" to Github (and much less amenable to me, I must admit) following topology:
*-. 92f9834' (merged PR #3, master)
*. \ 0547677' (merged PR #2)
* \ \ e6aa276' (merged PR #1)
|\ \ \
| | | * 92f9834 (PR #3)
| |_|/
|/| |
| | * 0547677 (PR #2)
| |/
|/|
| * e6aa276 (PR #1)
|/
* fb00b60 (origin/master)

(merges done with --no-ff)
...and pushing of that should succeed because Github in this case is able to infer "proper" relationship between the merge commit(s) and the PRs.
Is there truth to this?
I did mock the second topology variant where I merge the tip of each PR "in order" -- first [merge] the first PR into master then push master (this closed the PR, as expected), then [merge] the second PR into master, then attempt to push it and that's already where the pushing fails, with the same above error message. So I am not sure the topology necessarily figures into this.
I guess in general I would like to know how does Github facilitate distributed workflow that Git allows me, with say 3 open PRs which may or may not potentially have the same author (read: are developed in parallel), and one chief maintainer to merge everything into master? Git obviously facilitates this very well, what with the kind of topology I described first that I had developed locally (but couldn't push), and while I understand the benefits of branch protection (I am using it, after all), will I need to stop and e.g. rebase each PR in order, to merge everything?
Branch protection settings that are enabled (checked boxes, does not imply nested items are checked unless specifically listed):

Require a pull request before merging

Require approvals (number of approvals before merging: 1)
Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed


Require status checks to pass before merging
Require conversation resolution before merging
Require signed commits
Do not allow bypassing the above settings


The reason Github denies your push is more likely that you, the Github user, are not permitted to advance the master branch on Github. I doubt that Github cares how you merge the branches (whether as an octopus merge like you did or sequentially like it was suggested).

This is Github Enterprise (I've edited the question, just to be sure if it's relevant) and while I am not sure what exactly denying me to advance master hinges on, I can advance it if I remove the branch protection, so this isn't an authorization issue, if that's what you meant? Are you saying there's an issue with my user-repository permissions?

I think that is exactly what I meant. When you remove the branch protection, you (or anyone with push access to the repository) can advance the master branch.

Right, but if I remove branch protection and indeed am then allowed to advance the branch, I don't know what was preventing me from doing so when the branch protection was on. I can see we have a group for collaborators and I am on equal footing with the rest of the people [who can advance master with the branch protection on] as we're all in the group.

Yes, my take is that you would need to rebase (or merge) ech PR prior to merging into master.
This is the model of the need for PR maintainers to regularly update their branches against master so that the merge model is simpler.
One option is to create a merge branch PR that has the individual PRs all merged together.
generally I avoid any of this as the complexity of any issues that arise grows greatly.  I stick with the simple git model of updating each branch to master before merging.  I like to push each merge and see all tests pass. in CI

“regularly update their branches against master” no, this is definitely not needed (not unless you've enabled “Require branches to be up to date before merging” in addition to branch protection).

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' The OP wrote "strict branch protection", which GitHub defines as ticking "Require branches to be up to date before merging" (ref). That is consistent with GitHub rejecting the push of the merge of PR #2.

@tom Ah, thanks, I didn't know this option was called “strict branch protection” in the documentation. My point still stands that the OP's desired workflow contradicts this setting.

@tom and Gilles, I must confess I wrote "strict branch protection" in loose terms, I can see now that I do not have "Require branches to be up to date before merging" checked. I'll update my question to specify exactly which of the boxes are checked and which are not.

Edit: After re-reading @MichaelDurrant's answer, I realised he already described my ideas. I'm keeping my answer because it has more details.
There are two potential issues that need to be avoided when pushing:

GitHub might not recognise a push as closing a pull request.
GitHub might not permit the push due to branch protection rules.

You said you want to avoid using GitHub's web interface, but I'd still like to point out that the most reliable way to avoid both issues is to merge the PRs (individually) through GitHub's user interface, rather than through git. If you want to simplify the history, you can use "Squash and merge" instead of "Merge" when merging through GitHub's user interface. This will cherry-pick the commit to 'master', without creating a merge commit. The advantage is that it produces a simple linear history, the disadvantage is that it does not include the original commit in the graph (so if the original commit is signed, that signature will be lost; it can also make it harder to see whether a branch has been merged, and if you have dependent branches you may get spurious merge conflicts that are best resolved using careful rebasing). GitHub's user interface also makes it easy to bring the branch up to date. Alternatively, there is also an official command line tool as @Gilles points out.
When you merge and push through git, GitHub will recognise and close the pull request automatically as you noted (as long as the push includes the original commit, not a cherry-picked / rebased version).
Branch protection is trickier. GitHub will only accept a merge commit if the content matches the system-created merge for the PR (docs, credit to @Gilles). So the push will certainly fail if it contains commits from multiple PRs. And you've mentioned strict branch protection, which requires the branch to be up to date before merging. I have two tricks to make the push work:
A. Use the second topology and push the merge commits one by one, but before pushing the merge of PR #2 (which would fail), first push that merge to the branch of PR #2 (and re-approve PR #2 if necessary). Likewise, before you push the merge of PR #3, first push that merge to the branch of PR #3, etc. (This effectively brings the branches of the PRs up to date with 'master', but without any extra merge commits. It shouldn't cause much harm; the PR diff will still be mostly the same, it will just have a different base.) You could also do something similar using rebases or regular merges (merge 'master' into each PR).
B. Push the merged result (e.g. from your first topology) to a new branch and create a new pull request. Once the new PR is approved, it will allow you to push the merged result to 'master'. (You shouldn't merge the new PR through GitHub's user interface, because that will create an extra merge commit.)

If you do not tick "Require branches to be up to date before merging", then the second topology should work (with separate pushes to 'master', but without having to bring the branches up to date). I'm not sure why it's not working for you; here is a complete example that works for me.
New repository > Public (otherwise branch protection is not enforced) > Create repository.
git clone ...
cd ...
# add a workflow for a status check
mkdir -p .github/workflows
cat > .github/workflows/check.yml <<"EOF"
name: Check
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: |
          true
EOF
git add .github/workflows/check.yml
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push
# PR #1
git switch -c pr1 master
echo test > pr1.txt
git add pr1.txt
git commit -m "PR #1"
git push -u origin pr1
# PR #2
git switch -c pr2 master
echo test > pr2.txt
git add pr2.txt
git commit -m "PR #2"
git push -u origin pr2

Create branch protection rule:
Settings > Branches > Add branch protection rule
Branch name pattern: master
Tick "Require a pull request before merging"
  I unticked "Require approvals" because it requires two users
  Tick "Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed"
Tick "Require status checks to pass before merging"
  Leave "Require branches to be up to date before merging" unticked
  Search for status check named "check" and select it
  I did not tick "Require signed commits"
  Tick "Do not allow bypassing the above settings"
Create
Create pull requests:
Pull requests > New pull request > compare: pr1 > Create pull request > Create pull request.
Repeat for PR #2.
git switch master
git merge --no-ff pr1
git push
git merge --no-ff pr2
git push # succeeds

$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline --date-order
*   4444444 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Merge branch 'pr2'
|\
* \   3333333 Merge branch 'pr1'
|\ \
| | * 2222222 (origin/pr2, pr2) PR #2
| |/
|/|
| * 1111111 (origin/pr1, pr1) PR #1
|/
* 0000000 Initial commit


Thank you. If I merge master into the branch of each PR before merging it back into master, GH does not complain. Otherwise none of the topologies work (as I said in the question). As for "GH may not permit push due to branch protection rules" -- well, that was my question, in a sense -- exactly what does GH not like? It would seem your second point is contained in the first -- if GH recognizes a push as closing a PR, then the condition should be necessary and sufficient for the push to succeed, assuming commits are signed and PR was approved?

@ArmenMichaeli The second topology (with individual pushes) should succeed if you unticked "Require branches to be up to date before merging" and there were no merge conflicts. I'm not sure why it's failing for you. I've updated my answer with a detailed example. The only differences are that I didn't tick "Require approvals" (because it requires two users), and I didn't tick "Require signed commits" (but if the error was due to signatures then the push error message should have clearly said so).

Regarding the point "GH might not recognise a push as closing a PR", it isn't directly relevant to my answer, but it can be relevant in other situations -- e.g. if you use method B but with cherry-picking instead of merging, then GH would permit the push (thanks to the new PR) but it would not mark the other PRs as closed (which is very annoying).

I don't think GitHub does octopus merges. They're a lot more complicated to deal with, and I don't see where they would fit in GitHub's model where code normally comes in one pull request at a time. Even with merge queues, which can merge multiple pull requests in a single batch, the merges are still sequential.

how does Github facilitate distributed workflow that Git allows me

I'm not sure what you expect from GitHub, but its whole point compared to git is to centralize! The point is that everyone agrees that the master (or main or whatever other branch name) on GitHub is the reference one, and the master branch in every other repository is just an unofficial copy.

open PRs which may or may not potentially have the same author (read: are developed in parallel), and one chief maintainer to merge everything into master?

The maintainer just clicks the “merge” button. Each click results in one two-parent merge commit on the target branch.
The whole point of branch protection is that you can't push whatever you like to the master branch on GitHub. Only the code that has been published can be added to the branch (and, if the the branch protection rules say so, GitHub enforces that the code must have been approved and must pass status checks).

will I need to stop and e.g. rebase each PR in order, to merge everything?

There's no point in rebasing unless you enable “Require branches to be up to date before merging”. Which, presumably, you don't care about, since you're prepared to merge multiple branches at once, without doing any review of the result or running the CI on the result.

I thought I would just close the PRs by locally merging all of the branches (one for each PR) with a single new commit, which was effortless, obviously

If you try to push the result, GitHub sees a bunch of commits that are part of an approved pull request, plus a merge commit. Why would GitHub trust this merge commit? You might be sneaking in some additional changes, or you might have made a mistake in conflict resolution.
GitHub actually does have some undocumented heuristics that allow it to accept unreviewed commits on protected branches in some cases. I haven't found official documentation about these heuristics. A forum reply by a GitHub employee covers pull request approvals and I guess that also applies to pushes to protected branches. The rough idea is that GitHub only really protects the content and not the actual history (except for not allowing regressions, i.e. no force-pushes). So a merge commit is acceptable if its parents are themselves acceptable and its content are identical to the merge done on GitHub's server. This heuristic causes the first step of your sequential pushes to work: you're pushing one commit approved in the first pull request and one harmless merge commit. I don't know why it doesn't also allow your second push.

have as little as possible to do with Github's Web pages

GitHub is primarily designed for people who use its web interface. But if you really don't want to do that, there's an API and there are command-line tools for it such as gh (which is an official GitHub software).
